# How to display array data in form field in Ionic ReactJS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ionic-framework

I have some data fetched from Laravel API and stored in an array. I would like to display the value of the data in the form field so that users can edit the value. The array is as follows:
[Array Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDmYo.png)

I can display the other field data e.g `si_t_street1` that is not being stored in an array simply by using the variable name as the property value of 'name' of the field.
[Data Not Stored In Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cm0P.png)

Below is the snippet of my code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import * as api from '../../services/api';
import { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonButtons, IonBackButton, IonTitle, IonContent, IonButton, IonAlert, IonLoading, IonModal } from '@ionic/react';
import { NavContext } from "@ionic/react";

const AbroadApp: React.FC = (props: any) => {

  const { id } = props.match.params.id ?? ``;
  const isAddMode = (props.match.params.id) ? false : true;
  
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, setValue, errors, formState } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  function onSubmit(data: any) {
    return isAddMode
      ? createRegAbroad(data)
      : updateRegAbroad(id, data);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {

    if (!isAddMode) {
      api.getRegAbroadById(props.match.params.id).then(regAbroad => {

        let fields = [
          'si_t_street1',
          'si_t_street2',
          'si_t_street3',
          'street1'
        ];

        let regAbroadArr: any = [];
        regAbroadArr.push(regAbroad.data.data);

        fields.map(field => {
          setValue(field, regAbroadArr[0][field])
        })
        setLoading(false)
      });

    }
  }, []);
  
  return (
  
    <>
      <IonContent>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} onReset={reset}>
          <input name="id" ref={register} type="hidden" autoComplete="off" />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <label>
                Street 1{" "}
                <span className="text-danger">*</span>
               </label>
               <div className="form-group">
                 <input name="si_t_street1" ref={register} className={`form-control ${errors.si_t_street1 ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`} type="text" autoComplete="off" />
                 <div className="invalid-feedback">
                  {errors.si_t_street1?.message}
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12">
                <label>
                  Street 1{" "}
                  <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                 </label>
                 <div className="form-group">
                  <input name="street1" ref={register} className={`form-control ${errors.street1 ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`} type="text"
 autoComplete="off" value={country[0].street1} />
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                    {errors.street1?.message}
                  </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>                                       
        </form>
      </IonContent>
    </>
  
  );
  
}
export default AbroadApp;
```

I tried getting the value of `street1` property of the country array but the above code throws an error: cannot find name 'Country'. What is the right way to get the value to display?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you've defined your "country" variable.

Comment: This sounds silly but..how do i define the 'country' variable?